# Credit card masking - jquery

Tags: jquery, masking

I am trying to have a special formatting for a credit card input field using jquery with maskedinput.js.

Currently, my masking is xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
and i would like user to be forced to only input 6 first digits and four last ones and leave the numbers in the middle as '*' like:

1234-12**-****-1111

I have the following code to achieve this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function($){


            var creditcard = $("#creditcard").mask('9999-9999-9999-9999', {placeholder:'X'});


        });             

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="smart-wrap">
        <div class="smart-forms smart-container wrap-3">

            <div class="form-header header-primary">
                <h4><i class="fa fa-pencil-square"></i>Form </h4>
            </div><!-- end .form-header section -->

            <form method="post" action="/" id="account2">
                <div class="form-body">



                        <div class="section colm colm6">
                            <label for="creditcard" class="field-label">Credit Card Number</label>
                            <label for="creditcard" class="field">
                                <input type="text" id="creditcard" name="creditcard" class="gui-input" placeholder="Credit Card Number">
                            </label> 
                        </div><!-- end .section section -->

                    </div><!-- end .frm-row section -->

                </div><!-- end .form-body section -->
                <div class="form-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="button btn-primary"> Send Form </button>
                </div><!-- end .form-footer section -->
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

any clue how to achieve this ? Is there a special parameter for this?

Comment: Which masked input plugin are you using?  According the first one in google, https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput "*If your requirements aren't met by the predefined placeholders, you can always add your own*" and then explains how to define an "h" - so you could define s as `\*` then use s in the mask - but it all depends on which plugin you're using.